# How to make flag gets TRUE based on user submission Time?

Tags: apex

How to calculate Case record submission time based on that a check box field make it TRUE.

**Condition :** The `Urgencyflag__c` field must be true if user has submitted case record before 11:00 AM EST. How we can check? Can anyone help on that logic.

Comment: I've downvoted this because of the poor formatting, irrelevant tags, and not showing us your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing a trigger on the case object

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert) {
    for(Case c : Trigger.new){
        if(DateTime.now().hour() < 11){
            c.Urgencyflag__c = true;
        }
    }
}
```